# save image after capture phonegap ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I am developing IOS app using phonegap ... I used the default camera api so the user can take photo for his user profile pic.

the function is working fine but my problem the image that the user capture it wont save on the system files so I can retrieve it in other pages

here is my code

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

    // Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // Cordova is ready to be used!
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
      // console.log(imageData);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
      // console.log(imageURI);

      // Get image handle
      //
      document.getElementById('smallImage').src='img/me2.jpg';
      var smallImage = 'img/me2.jpg';

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
      // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, allowEdit: true,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    // 
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
```

how I can override the file ("img/me2.jpg") after the user take the pic using the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override the img/me2.jpg because that file is in the application bundle.

You have to save the captured image in the application data folder (e.g. using the PhoneGap's File API), then save the url in the localStorage from where you can retrieve it at any time.